# What do macros with multiple values separated by comma actually mean?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

While I was attempting a technical exam as part of a recruitment process I came across a question which has macros as shown below:

```
#define random 2,4
```

what does this mean? How can I define two values with a comma for a single macro?

Comment: You do not define "two values" but you define one replacement text. You can define any text that is used to replace the macro. What that text means is fully dependent on where you use that macro.

Comment: Whenever the `random` macro is used it will be replaced by `2,4`. Macros are pretty much a textual search-replace.

Comment: `int a[3] = { random };` ... `int x, y = random;` ... `pow(random) == 16` ...

Comment: It's not a great usage of macros...

Comment: @pmg that expands to `int x, y = 2,4;`.  which is a syntax error.

Comment: Even once you got to understand what it does - *please, please*, don't make/use macros like this.

Comment: What you've got so far is about the best we can do without more context. Did this exam show you `RANDOM` being used?

Comment: @user4581301 Just two random numbers, obviously. [xkcd](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png)

Comment: Just like when you're testing you need to see if your program does the wrong thing with unexpected inputs, sometimes you put bad ideas into a hiring test to see what the prospective programmer does with bad inputs.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili If I'm reading you right, `return random;` would be an interesting test of a new programmer's understanding of macros AND the comma operator. And if I'm not, it would still be interesting.

Comment: Right, @Wyck, my bad. I meant `int x, y = (random);`

Comment: @user4581301 yeah it was shown inside a if statement if i remember rightly. I think question was just trying to confuse us with multiple values. Thanks everyone for the answers I now understand it.

Comment: Thanks all . I got it now

Comment: @pmg your revised version expands to `int x, y = (2,4);` which leaves `x` uninitialized and assigns `y` a value of `4`. discarding the value of `2` according to the rules of [how the comma operator works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work).

Answer (score 6):

It literally replaces all occurrences of the [token](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) `random` with  `2,4`. The pre-processor is just a glorified text-replacement tool.

Comment: Does not replace text in C comments.  Aslo  replacement does not apply to character constants either like the poor code of `'random'`.  Perhaps other exceptions too.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica whether or not the comments get replaced doesn't matter though. I will add the character constants. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: "whether or not the comments get replaced doesn't matter though." --> Consider if a `random`  was `*/` .  Replacement would end a `/* random */` early.  But it does not as there was no replacement.  Perhaps all comments are replaced with a `' '` first.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies, I got it now. The question may be designed to confuse who is not well versed about macros.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica good point. Macros aren't allowed to start or end a comment iirc though.

Comment: If you said something like "…all occurrences of the token `random`…" you would cover the bases nicely.  Character constants and string literals are tokens in their own right and include the quotes, so they are never the token `random`.  Comments are replaced by white space so they are never the token `random` either.  If there was a macro `#define redefine(deterministic, random) …random…` then neither `random` is replaced by `2,4` as they are parameters to the macro. There are also variations on `#define macro(a,b) a ## b` plus an invocation `macro(ran,dom)` which generates the token `random`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't know those. I rephrased the answer accordingly. Thank you for the feedback!